# Partial rendering locally but can't be found in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

When deploying with capistrano to my VPS, I get the following error in my production.log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial application/nav_bar with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :jbuilder, :mustache]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/deployer/apps/feed_engine/releases/20120515125611/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/feed_engine/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/feed_engine/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
):
```

If I `ls app/views/application` then I see this `_nav_bar.html.slim` as expected. Why would the rendering of this partial work locally but not in production?

Comment: Do you use bundler? It seems to me that it cannot render template with slim ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you have the slim-rails gem in your gemfile?

Based on your error message, there is no handler for slim templated files.

I'd guess that you have slim-rails inside either the assets group, or the development group in your gemfile. Just move it out of those groups into the main part of the gemfile and re-bundle your application. This will get it to install properly in the production environment.

Comment: Yep I had no slim-rails on production, so I added it to the Gemfile, removed my .lock and redeployed. When I bundle on the server it shows slim-rals 1.0.3 but I still get the same error (and it isn;'t listed as a handler)

Comment: Did you refresh the `Gemfile.lock`? It's important to have this in production. How are you deploying to production, and what command are you using to bundle gems?

Comment: Okay I stopped and started both nginx and unicorn and now it renders. There is no css, but that's another issue.

Comment: Ah, yeah. You always have to restart your app when you add or remove gems; it has to initialize with the correct gems. You shouldn't have to restart nginx though.